# How to import Java X509 public key into .NET C#?

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, x509certificate2

I have a Java PublicKey (on Android), which I call getEncoded() on.

I am then able to export this byte array to a .NET environment, but when I try to:

```
new X509Certificate2(bytes)
```

it will throw an exception *System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cannot find the requested object.*.

PublicKey.getFormat() returns X.509, and PublicKey.getAlgorithm() returns EC.

What is the correct way to import a public key in C#?

Comment: What public key? RSA?

Comment: The algorithm is EC

Comment: Public key is not a certificate. And you are trying to instantiate a certificate object from just public key. You have to use key classes to impoirt your key.

Answer (score 0):

I found this wonderful small library targeting this exact issue:

https://github.com/BlackyPaw/X509Importer

Android outputs DER-encoded public key files which .NET does not support.